# IntelliJ ts/js extract method on all occurences

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellij-idea, webstorm

I'm quite new with IntelliJ Idea Ultimate 2020, and I trying to figure with the include refactoring functionalities on the software.

Do you know if it's possible to extract method from a sentence and apply this method to all occurrences easily and only with IDE?

Here is my example :

```
let a = 0;
let b = 2;
if (b === 2) {
// What I want to extract into a method 
    if (a === 0) {
        1 + 1;
    }
// What I also want to extract and it will be the same function
    if (a === 0) {
        1 + 1;
    }

    b = a + 1;
}
```

When I extract method I only get this:

```
let extracted = function (a) {
    if (a === 0) {
        1 + 1;
    }
};

let a = 0;
let b = 2;
if (b === 2) {
    extracted(a);

    if (a === 0) {
        1 + 1;
    }

    b = a + 1;
}
```

Is there a way to make IntelliJ automatically apply this to all occurrences?

```
 
let extracted = function (a) {
    if (a === 0) {
        1 + 1;
    }
};

let a = 0;
let b = 2;
if (b === 2) {
    extracted(a);

    extracted(a);
    
    b = a + 1;
}
```

If you know how to do it only with IDE (safer) thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently possible, please follow [WEB-39255](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-39255) for updates